# How to store and process result of a query in PHP array?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

My SQLite query in PHP goes like this:

```
function getTableData($l_name) {
   $db = new PDO("sqlite:../db/mydb.sqlite");
   $results = $db->exec("SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE L_ID = '" . $l_name; . "');";
   .......
}
```

My questions are:

- How can I get an array of Locations based on the `$results`? Could I just write `$results[0]` or `$results[$results.length]` to reference first and last records respectively?
- How would I use a foreach loop to loop through all records? Could I have `foreach ($results as $record)`, where `$record` is supposed to be a single record of Location in the current iteration?
- If I were to have a reference to an individual record, say using an array like this `records[0]`, how would I access this record's field (such as L_Name or L_ID)?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you want [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). You can do `$records = $results->fetchAll();`. Then you can loop over that array, ie. `foreach($records as $records){ $record['L_Name'] }`, or select it directly, ie. `$records[0]['L_Name']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code is just incorrect. Here goes the proper version:

```
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
];
$db = new PDO("sqlite:../db/mydb.sqlite", $opt);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE L_ID = ?");
$stmt->execute([$l_name]);
```

And now you can use $stmt variable in place of $results for your second question:

> How would I use a foreach loop to loop through all records? Could I have foreach ($results as $record), where $record is supposed to be a single record of Location in the current iteration?

Yes, you can.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE L_ID = ?");
$stmt->execute([$l_name]);
foreach ($stmt as $row)
{
    // do whatever
}
```

However, this method won't work with your other requirement.

> How can I get an array of Locations based on the $results? Could I just write $results[0] or $results[$results.length] to reference first and last records respectively?

To get a *real* array, you need `PDOStatement::fetchAll()‌​` method. However, to get the last element, the syntax will be different:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE L_ID = ?");
$stmt->execute([$l_name]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
$first = $results[0];
$last = $results[count($results)-1];

foreach ($results as $row)
{
    // do whatever
}
```

> If I were to have a reference to an individual record, say using an array like this records[0], how would I access this record's field (such as L_Name or L_ID)?

Just reference it. Any time you get a row, you can address its elements this way

```
echo $row['L_name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

`PDO::exec` does not receive the result set returned by the query. What you want is to use either the `PDO::query` methods or the `PDO::prepare` method, both of which give you a `PDOStatement` to work with. That in turn is traversable, allowing you to do something like:

```
$statement = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE L_ID = :id");
$statement->bindParam(':id', $l_name);
$statement->execute();

// Traverse the result set
while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
    // Do something with each $row here
}

// Alternatively, you can load all results into an array:
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Also notice that the example above uses `PDOStatement::bindParam` to use your variable with the query. This is vital to preventing SQL injection attacks. You can read more about that here: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score -1):

Here is basic code that loops through the results of your query, allowing you to reference fields in each record returned:

```
foreach ($db->$query("SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE L_ID = '" . $l_name . "'") as $row)
{
    // $row will contain an array to the current record
    // Address fields using the field name in quotes inside the brackets next to $row
    $variable1 = $row['field1name'];
    $variable2 = $row['field2name'];
}
```